# Null Dereference - Fortify scan with HashMap.EntrySet()

Tags: java, fortify

I am retrieving the key and values from the Hashmap using the entrySet(). The code is working fine but the fortify scan is complaining the Null Dereference at map dot entrySet. Below is the code sample. Please suggest.

1. I tried to put the null checks on the entry.getKey and the entry.getValue().
2. I tried the null checks on paramMap.entrySet() as well

```
for (Entry<EnumType, Integer> entry : paramMap.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getKey().name().startsWith("xyz")) {
        if (input.charAt(entry.getValue() - 1) == '1') {
            list.add(entry.getKey().name().substring(interactionPrefix.length()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `paramMap` assigned? Can it ever be null?

Comment: The map is constructed within a static method with some static value.It is having a check from the method caller and if the map is null then it will not come to this point.

Comment: Since the null check is elsewhere, it will be difficult for static code analysis to determine that `paramMap` can't be null in this context.

Comment: I tried to put the null check in the method itself and still it is not working.

Comment: I found the solution for this issue. Instead of using the map.entrySet i used the forEach Method which internally take care of the iteration over the key and values. paramMap.forEach((key, value) ->{if (key.name().startsWith("xyz")) {
        if (input.charAt(value - 1) == '1') {
            list.add(key.name().substring(interactionPrefix.length()));
        }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the map.entrySet i used the forEach Method which internally take care of the iteration over the key and values.

```
paramMap.forEach((key, value) ->{
if (key.name().startsWith("xyz")){ 
if (input.charAt(value - 1) == '1'){ list.add(key.name().substring(interactionPrefix.length()));
}
});
```

Comment: I suggest that you take a moment to format your code so that it is more readable for future visitors.